# Log4net multiple loggers - File logger not working

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Following configuration logs to Eventlog and it works for SmtpSender. But the filelogger does not log, it creates the log file in the path, but does not do any debug logs.

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />      
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</root>
<logger additivity="false" name="SmtpLogger">
  <level value="FATAL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="RollingFileAppender">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

But when I change the root logger to RollingFileAppender it logs to file,

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />      
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
<logger additivity="false" name="SmtpLogger">
  <level value="FATAL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="RollingFileAppender">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Any idea why this happens? How can I get file logger working in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the logging work, in fact I did this as an experiment and it worked.

Added RollingFileAppender to the root element,

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />      
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />    
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
<logger additivity="false" name="SmtpLogger">
<level value="FATAL"/>
<appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="RollingFileAppender">
<level value="DEBUG"/>
<appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the appender confuriguration, however the easiest way to figure out what goes wrong is enable internal debugging. This will tell you what goes wrong in the rolling file appender:

> There are 2 different ways to enable internal debugging in log4net.
>   These are listed below. The preferred method is to specify the
>   log4net.Internal.Debug option in the application's config file.
>
> • Internal debugging can also be enabled by setting a value in the
>   application's configuration file (not the log4net configuration file,
>   unless the log4net config data is embedded in the application's config
>   file). The log4net.Internal.Debug application setting must be set to
>   the value true. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

> This setting is read immediately on startup an will cause all internal
>   debugging messages to be emitted.
>
> • To enable log4net's internal debug programmatically you need to set
>   the log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging property to true. Obviously
>   the sooner this is set the more debug will be produced.
>
> Internal debugging messages are written to the console and to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system. If the application does not have a
>   console the messages logged there will be lost. Note that an
>   application can redirect the console stream by setting the
>   System.Console.Out. The Trace system will by default send the message
>   to an attached debugger (where the messages will appear in the output
>   window). If the process does not have a debugger attached then the
>   messages are sent to the system debugger. A utility like DebugView
>   from http://www.sysinternals.com may be used to capture these
>   messages.
>
> As log4net internal debug messages are written to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system it is possible to redirect those
>   messages to a local file. You can define a trace listener by adding
>   the following to your application's .config file:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ...
</configuration>

Make sure that the process running your application has permission to write to this file.
```

[log4net faq](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I already did this. There were no exceptions and it correctly configures the RollingfileAppender. Permission is enough, when the RollingFileAppender is made as the root appender it works fine.